# How to specify queue name while posting message with RawRabbit

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, rawrabbit

What I found so far, that it is possible to install `RawRabbit.Enrichers.Attributes`package and configure message class with attributes:

```
[Queue(Name = "my_queue"]
private class AttributedMessage
{       
}
```

and set

```
var client = RawRabbitFactory.CreateSingleton(new RawRabbitOptions
{
    Plugins = plugin => plugin.UseAttributeRouting()
});
```

But I would rather want to specify queue name along with publish command to keep it more flexible:

```
await _busClient.PublishAsync(message /*some_config_here???*/);
```

Is it possible with RawRabbit 2.0.0-rc5?

Answer (score -1):

I think this may help you:

```
    static async Task Publish()
    {
        var config = new RawRabbitConfiguration
        {
            Username = "YOUR_RMQ_USER",
            Password = "YOUR_RMQ_PWD",
            Port = 5672,
            VirtualHost = "/",
            Hostnames = { "YOUR_RMQ_HOST_OR_IP" }
        };
        var bus = BusClientFactory.CreateDefault(config);


        await bus.PublishAsync(
            message: yourAwesomeMessagePayload,
            configuration: ctx => ctx.WithExchange(BuildExchangeConfig)
                                     .WithRoutingKey("custom.message.routing.key")
            );

        Console.WriteLine("message published!");
    }

    static void BuildExchangeConfig(IExchangeConfigurationBuilder e)
    {
        e.WithName("YOUR_EXCHANGE_NAME")
            .WithAutoDelete(false)
            .WithDurability(true)
            .WithType(ExchangeType.Topic);
    }
```